# Delegate method not firing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

Just when I thought I had my head around how delegates work, it seems I am missing something.

I've setup a delegate like so:

**ViewControllerA.h**

```
@protocol LoginDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)userLoginSuccessful;

@end
@interface BBLoginViewController : BBBaseViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <LoginDelegate> delegate; 

@end
```

**ViewControllerA.m**

```
-(void)someMethod 
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userLoginSuccessful)]){
                [self.delegate userLoginSuccessful];
            }
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**ViewControllerB.m**

```
    #import "ViewControllerA.h"

    @interface ViewControllerB () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, LoginDelegate>


    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {

        ViewControllerA *loginViewController = [[ViewControllerA alloc]init];
        loginViewController.delegate = self;

    }

#pragma mark - Login Delegate

-(void) userLoginSuccessful
{
  NSLog (@"Delegate fired!");
}
```

After all this my delegate method does not fire. What am I doing wrong?  I looked at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134334/delegate-method-not-being-called) and when checking the delegate is not nil - it is not. Its set to `ViewControllerB`.

Comment: Check your delegate method. you have defined this protocol method `userLoginSuccessful` and you are calling `-(void)expanItemImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap`

Comment: And you do not need to check if your delegate responds to the protocol selector since you defined it correctly as a type conforming to the LoginDelegate protocol.

Comment: Copy and paste error - updated the question. Sorry gents. I removed the IF statement checking if the selector responds to the delegate and it still doesn't get called

Comment: Do you reach the line [self.delegate userLoginSuccessful]; ?

Comment: I reach the if statement. Which never executes. Removing the statement and just calling [self.delegate userLoginSuccessful]; doesn't work either.

Comment: @giorashc why? Its always better to check your delegate respond to the corresponding selector. You can avoid a crash some times.

Comment: It's probably not the same instance of ViewControllerA. How do you add ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB ?

Comment: @Anil true for optional methods declared in a protocol but in his case he has only one required method.

Comment: Its better if you follow some conventions, will help you future :)

Comment: to be on the safe side I totally agree

Comment: I've always used the if statement to check the selector as I have had crashes before due to that very reason. Now I just implement it and know 100% I will never get a crash because it was sent to a class that has no idea what its about.

Comment: @Tander this can go either way since now you will not know you have a problem espcially if the selector does not preform something that is visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `delgate` before presenting `ViewControllerB`. The below code is not required anymore

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
     ViewControllerA *loginViewController = [[ViewControllerA alloc]init];
     loginViewController.delegate = self;

  }
```

Dont do like that. It will give you unexpected results. Remember always set the delegate before moving to the next view. If you are presenting modally just before `presentViewController` of if you are using segue in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: "It will give you unexpected results".  Errr, I think the results can be predicted exactly.

Comment: @trojanfoe lol:) yeah exactly.. not the result what you intended!

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    ViewControllerA *loginViewController = [[ViewControllerA alloc]init];
    loginViewController.delegate = self;

}
```

Will create a `ViewControllerA` object and then (almost) immediately destroy it and is not what you intended.

You probably want to be setting the delegate in the `prepareForSegue:` method anyway...

Comment: +1 - **(almost) immediately destroy it and is not what you intended.**

Comment: ViewControllerB is present modally over viewControllerA. I am not using pprepareForSegue method.

Comment: @Tander Well your code is not how you create and use view controllers is it.

Comment: @Tander try to set the delegate before presenting `ViewControllerB`

Comment: @Anil when would be the best time to set the delegate?

Comment: That depends. I would prefer setting delegate before moving to the next view. If you are presenting modally just before `presentViewController` of if you are using segue in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: Anyway currently what you are doing is wrong. if you can show me the presentation code i will point out

Comment: @Anil You're correct. I was setting the delegate incorrectly while presenting the view controller. I needed to set it just before presentViewController method - it works perfectly now. Make your comment an answer and I will accept it. Thank you!